# Tool to check code duplication in C#

Tags: c#

I need to check if my codes have a duplication. Is there any free application for code duplication refactoring tool for C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check :

**Simian** (http://www.redhillconsulting.com.au/products/simian/), based on source code. Works with plenty languages.

**Clone Detective a Visual Studio plugin** (http://www.codeplex.com/CloneDetectiveVS). (It uses ConQAT internally)

Answer (score 1):

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) has a [duplicates search](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/code_quality.html) if you are already using TeamCity.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Simian - Similarity Analyser](http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/). It is a command line tool, but it works well.